# jQuery Mobile Switch to "page" thats already in dom with .changePage()

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, swipe

Right now my DOM has three divs with `data-roll="page"`, all of them have unique id's. If I use the following code it works but jQuery Mobile is creating a new node rather than switching to the already existing node.

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        console.log(nextpage);
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage.attr('id'), {transition: 'slide'});
    }
});
```

I have also tried passing just nextpage to the `.chagePage` method but when ever the pages have an id set I get the following error.

```
TypeError: b.split is not a function
```

So I'm looking to switch directly to the already existing "page" thats in the DOM rather than create a new one from my swipeleft handler.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried passing-in a jQuery object rather than a string?

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', "swipeleft", function(){
    var $nextPage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if ($nextPage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage($nextPage, { transition: 'slide' });
    }
}).delegate('.ui-page', "swiperight", function(){
    var $prevPage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if ($prevPage .length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage($prevPage, { transition: 'slide', reverse : true });
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V3CXF/

Otherwise I think you have to prepend a hash mark to your string ID to make it a valid selector:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', "swipeleft", function(){
    var $nextPage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if ($nextPage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#' + $nextPage[0].id, { transition: 'slide' });
    }
}).delegate('.ui-page', "swiperight", function(){
    var $prevPage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if ($prevPage .length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#' + $prevPage[0].id, { transition: 'slide', reverse : true });
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V3CXF/1/

Notice I swapped `.live()` out for `.delegate()` as `.live` is now depreciated (as of jQuery Core 1.7). If you are using jQuery Core 1.7 or newer, you can use `.on()` instead.

Docs for `.live()`: http://api.jquery.com/live

Comment: I have tried to pass the object to it and have tried your sugjestion of prefixing the id with #. Both result in this error in firebug.

TypeError: b.split is not a function

Comment: @hcker2000 I added demos to show my code working. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/V3CXF/

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but for some reason if you use a number as the id it fails to work. There has to be some text in the id for it to work correctly. I also reworked the js fiddle a bit to work with 1.7+'s .on method and it will work with the jquery object rather than the id too. http://jsfiddle.net/qGJpt/7/

Comment: @hcker2000 That is because starting an ID with a number is invalid. Here is a great answer to a S.O. question regarding valid IDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: I remember reading that spec some place a while back. I guess normally I just never try to do what I did today. I really appreciate all the help.